# In clojure use and alias not working within a do block

Tags: clojure

In clojure when I do :

```
(do 
    (use 'oe.model.modelcore) 
    (alias 'model 'oe.model.modelcore) 
    (str ::model/record)
)
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Invalid token: ::modelcore/a
java.lang.Exception: Unmatched delimiter: )
java.lang.Exception: Unmatched delimiter: )
```

However, if I run the commands separately **outside of the do block** they work:

```
(use 'oe.model.modelcore)
(alias 'model 'oe.model.modelcore)
(str ::model/record )
```

: returns :

```
:oe.model.modelcore/record
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a tricky edge case known as the Gilardi Scenario: http://technomancy.us/143

The whole do must be compiled before the require runs. The above link shows you how to work around it by resolving the var at runtime with ns-resolve.

Also: calling bare use and alias outside the ns form is usually not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This issue results from the interaction of read time and run time.

In the first example, the entire form is read before it is executed. `::model/record` gives the invalid token exception because there is not namespace aliased as `model` yet.

In the second example, the first form is read, then executed. The the same with the second and then the third. By the time the third form is read in, there is a namespace aliased as `model` so no exception is thrown.